# lib/searchkick/model.rb:70:in `searchkick_reindex'

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a model with name **Actor** and the model looks like the following snippet

```
class Actor 
      include Mongoid::Document  
      field :name, type: String 
      field :birthName, as: :birth_name, type: String 
      field :date_of_birth, type: Date 
      field :height, type: Measurement 
      field :bio, type: String 
    searchkick
end
```

when I try to reindex my model using  `Actor.reindex` I am getting the following error which shows the root cause as **Index already exists**.

```
irb(main):001:0> Actor.reindex
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [actors_development_20170209175219593/TKOPkMY1TsGNEYmWlVCKo
A] already exists","index_uuid":"TKOPkMY1TsGNEYmWlVCKoA","index":"actors_development_20170209175219593"}],"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [actors_development_20170209175219593/TKO
PkMY1TsGNEYmWlVCKoA] already exists","index_uuid":"TKOPkMY1TsGNEYmWlVCKoA","index":"actors_development_20170209175219593"},"status":400}
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:201:in `__raise_transport_error'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:318:in `perform_request'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:128:in `perform_request'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-5.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/api/namespace/common.rb:21:in `perform_request'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-5.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/indices/create.rb:86:in `create'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-2.1.1/lib/searchkick/index.rb:14:in `create'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-2.1.1/lib/searchkick/index.rb:177:in `create_index'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-2.1.1/lib/searchkick/index.rb:226:in `reindex_scope'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-2.1.1/lib/searchkick/model.rb:70:in `searchkick_reindex'
        from (irb):1
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /home/ravi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

Since the error is showing **Index already exists**, then I deleted the index from elasticsearch and tried to run again but, it is giving me the same error **index already exists**

Can anyone please help to find the reason behind this error

Thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of debugging ,I found out the reason behind that error.

I am using Searchkick v2.1.1 with Elasticsearch v.5.0.1...which is giving me the transport error.

Then I replaced Elasticsearch v5.0.1 with v2.4.3 .Then it started indexing properly. I guess there is a compatibility issue between searchkick v2.1.1 and Elasticsearch v5.0.1